# NSNumberFormatter for 2 Decimal Places

Tags: ios, objective-c, number-formatting, nsnumberformatter

I have some amount that i want to Display in local Style.

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];
numberFormatter.locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle;
numberFormatter.usesGroupingSeparator = YES;

NSString* amountText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ab %@€",[numberFormatter stringFromNumber:someDoubleNumber]];
```

Problem is that this is also displaying the currency and that is something that i don't want. Basically what i am looking for is displaying that decimal should be according to local Style with 2 numbers after decimal for example `0.00` or in germany `0,00` with my code i am achieveing this requirement but i am also getting the additionally the currency symbol which i  don't  want.

Answer (score 0):

Anybody still looking for an answer i achieved it by

```
[numberFormatter setCurrencySymbol:@""];
```